# Customise JSON in pipeline expression builder of ADF

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

There is a variable in ADF that holds the below value.

```
@json(concat('{','"S.No":',variables('counter'),',"Input Table":"Input TblName","Output Table":"[Tbl1, tbl2, Tbl3]", "Status":"Successful"}'))
```

I pass this variable to a logic app using Web activity and use 'Create HTML Table' to convert this json to a table.

Apparently, the below is what I will get if I do so

| SNo | Input Table | Output Table | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Input Table Name | [Tbl1, tbl2, Tbl3] | Successful |

But I want it to be displayed as below.

| SNo | Input Table | Output Table | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Input Table Name | Tbl1 | Successful |
| 2 | Input Table Name | tbl2 | Successful |
| 3 | Input Table Name | Tbl3 | Successful |

Is there any way to achieve this is ADF pipeline expression builder

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the JSON in **`Logic Apps`** itself using below design and process:

**`Input:`**

```
{

"Input Table": "Rith Table",
"Output Table":"[Tbl1, tbl2, Tbl3]",
"Status":"Successful"

}
```

**`Design:`**

[image]

Then:

[image]

**`Output:`**
[image]

[image]

**`Codeview to Replicate the same:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@split(body('Parse_Json')?['Output Table'], ',')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Create_HTML_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "format": "HTML",
                    "from": "@variables('var')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Table"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var",
                            "value": {
                                "Input Table": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['Input Table']}",
                                "Output Table": "@{replace(replace(items('For_each'),'[',''),']','')}",
                                "Sno": "@{variables('var2')}",
                                "Status": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['Status']}"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Increment_variable": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Increment_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "IncrementVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@outputs('Compose_2')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Input Table": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Output Table": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Status": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the variable counter works for the tables naming you can do the following:

```
@json(concat('{','"S.No":',variables('counter'),',"Input Table":"Input TblName","Output Table":"tbl',variables('counter'),'", "Status":"Successful"}'))
```

If not you will need to have a list of JSON objects like this:

```
@json(concat('{','"S.No":',variables('counter'),',"Input Table":"Input TblName","Output Table":"Tbl1", "Status":"Successful"},{','"S.No":',variables('counter'),',"Input Table":"Input TblName","Output Table":"tbl2", "Status":"Successful"},{','"S.No":',variables('counter'),',"Input Table":"Input TblName","Output Table":"Tbl3", "Status":"Successful"},'))
```